# How to store a value from firebase in a global variable?

Tags: multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read a value from my Firebase Database and assign it to a global variable. However, the variable always seems to be null. I checked many forums and they all say that I need to attach a 'callback' as this is an asynchronous task. Can someone help me out with the exact code?

```
getServerTime.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    system_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    getServerTime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            server_time_long = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);




                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

          t1.setText(String.valueOf(server_time_long));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in which you can store a value that you get from a Firebase database in global variable because the `onDataChange()` method is called `asynchronous`. This means that `setText()` method is called before you are trying to get the data from the database and that's why is always `null`.

To solve this problem, you need to move this line of code:

```
t1.setText(String.valueOf(server_time_long));
```

inside `onDataChange()` method. This can be done like this:

```
getServerTime.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                system_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                getServerTime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        long server_time_long = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                        t1.setText(String.valueOf(server_time_long));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
        });
```

If you want to use that value outside that method, i suggest you see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: If you need that data outside, then just follow the stepts explained in that answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I do need to use that value outside that method. I just checked your other answer and I have a few questions(I'm very new to Android, so please bear with me):

1) Where exactly would you call the data from? As in, can you give me a more tailored answer?

2) It says that I need to declare 'database' in new Database().mRead... . What do I define it as?

Comment: 1) You call that data exactly where you need. 2) The steps (3 of them) you need to follow are explained in that post. 3) Yes, you need to create a new object of `Database` in order to achieve that.

Comment: Firebase doesn't allow Database objects to be created from the 3.0 version, apparently. Should I use databaseReference or FirebaseDatabase instead? If so, how would the syntax change? If the URL of my database was "https://fir-authtest-dc75a.firebaseio.com/", how would you write the code? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what would I input as the string for 'child'? The name of the child which contains my servertime value?

Comment: Definitely you shoul use `DatabaseReference`. You need to use only this oline: `DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` and you are connected.

Comment: I just edited my question, please refer to it again. Thanks!

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Sorry! I've edited it back to the original question. My new question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831670/having-trouble-with-interfaces-in-java-regarding-retrieval-and-storage-of-data-f