# Having trouble with interfaces in Java regarding retrieval and storage of data from a Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the following code: I get the toast messages in the following order:

"Inside mCheckInforInServer" --> "Posted text" --> "Took Value"

How do I change my code to get it in the following order:

"Inside mCheckInforInServer" --> "Took Value" --> "Posted text"

**The Three Functions**

```
getServerTime.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    system_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    getServerTime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            server_time_long = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);


public interface OnGetDataListener {
    public void onStart();

    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data);

    public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError);
}

public void mReadDataOnce(final OnGetDataListener listener) {
    listener.onStart();

    getServerTime = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Arjun/ServerTime");
    getServerTime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listener.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Took value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFailed(databaseError);
        }
    });


}

private void mCheckInforInServer() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside mCheckInforInServer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mReadDataOnce(new OnGetDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN START GET DATA HERE

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot data) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA SUCCESS HERE
            server_time_display.setText(String.valueOf(data));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Posted text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //DO SOME THING WHEN GET DATA FAILED HERE
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to post text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

**Where I'm calling the function**

I am calling the function on the on-click event of a button:

```
     get_times.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {





           mCheckInforInServer();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the order of displaying those Toasts because `onDataChange()` method is called `asynchronous` which means that the Toast that you are trying to display `Posted text` is called even before you are trying to get the data from the database. That's why you are having that order of execution.

To solve this, all you need to get from the database must be used inside `onDataChange()` method otherwise will be `null`.

If you want to use the data from the database outside `onDataChange()` method, i suggest you see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: Can you please be more specific by rewriting the code here? From what I can tell, what I've posted here and your answer on that post are pretty much the same. But, it still doesn't work for me. If I want to assign the value of the timestamp from the database to a global variable, how  would I go about it? I also don't understand what to pass as the 'child' parameter; android studio also says 'child is never used'. So, please clarify these points for me. And it would be awesome if you could literally rewrite the code! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Arjun, there is no way in which you can pass the value of the timestamp from the database to a global variable because this how things works when it comes to asynchronous methods. The only thing you need to do is to use the value of your `timestamp` inside the `onDataChange()` method. That's is. It's the simples way.

Comment: Then, what exactly do you mean when you say 'use the data from the database outside onDataChange() method'?

Comment: I mean that if you want to use the data outside the onDatachange you need use my answer from that post. Do you think that my answer helped you?